# Defining a class property with type void (not a method)

Tags: c#, oop, void

I'm trying to build a class called GameObject (for consoleApplication game), and that GameObject should have a function "onFrame" that is called, let's say, every 0.1 seconds.

But the catch is, that this function (void) should be unique for every gameObject - let's say I have GameObject: G1, G2. G1 will increase a variable by 1 in it's onFrame, and G2 will print something to the console (just examples).

Is it possible to do that?

I tried doing that in this way:

```
class GameObject 
{
    public void onFrame;

    public GameObject (void of) //constructor
    {
        onFrame = of;
        Thread t = new Thread(runOnFrame);
        t.isBackgroundThread = true;
        t.Start();
    }

    protected void runOnFrame () 
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            if (onFrame != null) onFrame(); //EDIT: that (0) was typed by mistake
        }
    }
}
```

And the main function:

```
public static int i = 0;
static void Main (string[] args)
{
    GameObject G1 = new GameObject(new void (){
        i++;
    });
    GameObject G2 = new GameObject(new void () {
        Console.WriteLine("OnFrame is being called!");
    })
}
```

But it doesn't seem like being the right way to do that...
Is it possible? And how do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for is an `Action`, which is the same as a `void` delegate:

```
class GameObject 
{
    public Action onFrame;

    public GameObject (Action of) //constructor
    {
        onFrame = of;
        Thread t = new Thread(runOnFrame);
        t.isBackgroundThread = true;
        t.Start();
    }

    protected void runOnFrame () 
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            if (onFrame != null) onFrame();
        }
    }
}
```

However I would suggest using a `Timer` instead of calling `thread.Sleep` in a continuous loop.

One way to pass in a delegate is to use lambda syntax:

```
GameObject G1 = new GameObject(() => i++ );
```

The `()` is a placeholder for an empty input parameter set:

Comment: Shouldn't `onFrame` be of type `Action<int>`?

Comment: Amazing, thanks! And can you add to the answer the way to define an action - like, how will you define it in the main function? (so it will be useful for future visitors)

Comment: @MatiasCicero Good catch.  I didn't see that in the usage.

Comment: @MatiasCicero Now that I look again - the delegate is called _with_ a parameter in the class but _without_ outside the class, so I'm not sure what the expected usage is.

Comment: Wait, why does it seem like I want to pass an int parameter? It should be like: void onFrame () {...} with no arguments... EDIT - just removed that (0) that was typed by mistake. Thanks again :)

Comment: @DStanley It seems the int parameter was a typo (refer to edited question), so a plain `Action` should be fine. You're right :)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a delegate.

Your "onFrame" definition should look something like this:

```
public delegate void SimpleDelegate();
public SimpleDelegate onFrame;
```

Your constructor would become this:

```
public GameObject (SimpleDelegate of)
{
    onFrame = of;
    Thread t = new Thread(runOnFrame);
    t.isBackgroundThread = true;
    t.Start();
}
```

Then later, something like this:

```
GameObject G1 = new GameObject(new SimpleDelegate(() => {
    i++;
}));
```

.....

Comment: My apologies, fixed yet again. Now using a lamda

Comment: Note: It's best practice to make the onFrame variable private. It was left public in this example because it was public in the original question.

Comment: What is the difference between SimpleDelegate and Action?

Comment: I was previously unaware of "Action", so I guess I learn something every day. There is effectively no difference. "Action" is a system-defined delegate, and "SimpleDelegate" is a user-defined delegate. In fact, if you "go to definition" for "Action" in Visual Studio, you will see a nearly identical definition as the SimpleDelegate presented here.